# Image Literal - Editor placeholder in source file, cannot make it work

Tags: swift

When adding an icon to the assets folder it says "Editor placeholder in source file". Does anyone know the solution?

```
let logo: UIImageView = {
    let l = UIImageView()
        l.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "128x128")
        l.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        l.layer.masksToBounds = true
        //l.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    return l
}()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just type `image literal` and it will complete with default icon.
[image]

Double click on this icon and it will open the media library right side of it.
[image]

then pick the image you want
[image]